# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to add a new text to a existing in the simplest way posible, in my case I can only modify the script that is inside a paragraph element but Im getting this error `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node`. How can I make this works in the shortest code possible?

```html
<!-- Many elements above this -->
<p>
  This a part of the text
  <script>
    document.currentScript.parentNode.appendChild(" and this is the new text added");
  </script>
</p>
<!-- Many elements under this -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create the text as `textNode` using [**createTextNode()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) method like,

```
const textNode = document.createTextNode(" and this is the new text added");
```

and pass the node created as parameter to appendChild like,

```
document.currentScript.parentNode.appendChild(textNode);
```

And the modified snippet as sollows,

```html
<!-- Many elements above this -->
<p>
  This a part of the text
  <script>
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(" and this is the new text added");
    document.currentScript.parentNode.appendChild(textNode);
  </script>
</p>
<!-- Many elements under this -->
```